Can a vacuum reverse rusting of iron?
In this answer, by appeal to Le Chatelier's principle, it is predicted that increased pressure would accelerate the process of rusting iron. Symmetrically, Le Chatelier's principle suggests that decreased pressure would slow down the rusting process.
Can sufficiently low pressure reverse the process, in theory? Le Chatelier's principle doesn't allow for this, but outgassing from vapor pressure is a real phenomenon in low-pressure laboratories.
Answers may assume any conditions that would reliably cause rusting in a laboratory setting; in particular, the air may be humid.

I thought this would be easy to answer on my own, but two back-of-napkin attempts differ in whether it's possible, and search results are mostly about outgassing in metalworking contexts. I don't have the equipment to test this myself.

One can certainly dissociate iron and oxygen at high enough temperatures, but they are above the temperature at which iron oxides evaporate... so you would get an iron oxygen gas or even plasma mixture, which is not what you want.

Does you mean thermodynamically or kinetically?

If reaction is highly exothermic, trying to drive equilibrium with Le Chatelier isn't viable in practice. Putting some rust in high vacuum barely does anything at all.

Yes; oxides can be reduced to pure metals in low-oxygen atmospheres, especially with heating.
Recall that Nature acts to reduce the Gibbs free energy $G\equiv H-TS$ (enthalpy $H$, temperature $T$, entropy $S$) for systems in thermal and mechanical contact with their surroundings. A negative $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S$ corresponds to spontaneity. Note the tradeoff between the enthalpy and entropy changes; either a sufficient enthalpy decrease (from strong bonding) or a sufficient entropy increase (from additional particle configurations) can drive a process forward.
And the higher the temperature, the stronger the influence of $\Delta S$.
From this we can conclude that any reaction we see that turns a gas into condensed matter—which decreases entropy, $\Delta S<0$—must be exothermic ($\Delta H<0$, and indeed $\Delta H<T\Delta S$). Oxidation eliminates gas and thus produces a large entropy decrease. So why is oxidation (sometimes) spontaneous? Because the strong bonding of the compound releases an exothermic latent heat of reaction that heats the universe, increasing its entropy more than enough to compensate.
At higher temperatures, though, the entropy decrease makes the $-T\Delta S$ term too large, and oxidation ceases to be spontaneous; instead, reduction occurs into pure metal as the oxidation reaction reverses.
This is shown graphically by the Ellingham diagram:

The way to use this diagram is to extend a line from the $\mathrm O$ point on the top left to the reaction of interest at the temperature of interest. The line then passes though the equilibrium partial pressure of oxygen. A higher partial pressure makes oxidation spontaneous; a lower partial pressure makes reduction spontaneous. Note, however, that the partial pressure you need to maintain to reverse rusting at room temperature is very small indeed, and that the diagram shows only equilibrium states, without information on how fast the process occurs.

In fact the rate of spontaneous decomposition of iron oxide, at room temperature, is phenomenally low -- so low that I suspect the majority of decompositions will come from occasional nonthermal high-energy particles, not from excitation by the thermal bath.
Also, eyeballing the diagram, the equilibrium concentration of oxygen is something on the order of one oxygen molecule per Milky Way-sized sphere.

We could "cheat" and put the rust in space, where it will encounter the occasional hydrogen atom or molecule.

Rust may decompose into water vapor and iron oxides very slowly in perfect vacuum. Next, these iron oxides may evaporate even slower. That doesn't mean the process of rusting is reversed, because you cannot get solid metallic iron back. It all converts to vapor eventually.

"because you cannot get solid metallic iron back" How do you think metallic iron is produced from ore? The surrounding oxygen pressure is decreased.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@Chemomechanics Metallic iron is liquid if obtained carbothermally. If there was no reducing agent and the temperature was room temperature, (as is the case when rust forms), there would be no way to get iron as a solid.
